# Can you create an initialize method for DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, class-library

I need to create a service, but the service needs to be in a already existing Class Library file and also the new service needs to start running after the Class Library is installed.
Is there a way to create an Init() method or other way to start service inside in Class Library?
The project supports max .NET 3.5

Sorry if it sounds dumb, i'm new to the Class Library stuff

Comment: by word *service* you mean Windows service ?

Comment: @Vladimir unfortunately not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, class libraries don't support initialization like this.

Note that the library wouldn't even be loaded until it's first used anyway. You could write a *type* initializer for some appropriate type, and make that start the service - but personally I'd make it explicit if at all possible. (Doing lots of work in type initializers can lead to difficult-to-diagnose issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Not a great way to do this. But you can create a singleton for initializing the things that need to be done for the library.  Then you can get an instance of the singleton in the library classes that rely on the initialization code.  The first time the singleton is instanced, the initialization is done in the private constructor.  The initialization code only gets run once this way.

Not the most elegant way to achieve this but it will insure that the necessary initialization gets done for the library.